# Representation by Poisson transform

Tags: distributions

In physics papers that dealing with multiplicity distributions in high energy collisions, I have met with that some probability distributions can be expressed as a Poisson transform. See, eg., [International Journal of Modern Physics A 1987 02:05, 1447-1547](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0217751X87000806). For example, the negative binomial dsitribution can be expressed as the Poisson transform of the gamma distribution.

These paper that I have read take this as a fact. I wonder what is (are) the assumption(s) or how widely true is this?

Comment: That link is to a 100 page paywalled article, so it is difficult to comment on what it says.  But a connection between the Poisson and gamma distributions and the negative binomial distribution is well known, for example as [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma%E2%80%93Poisson_mixture)

Comment: @Henry, thank you for your answer. Sorry for the paywalled source. The exact wording there is: "Each of these distribution can be represented by a Poisson transform, i.e. a (positive weight) superposition of Poisson distribution." And yes, this is known for the gamma distribution. Even, if the case of the generalized gamma distribution, the result is known to be the Fox's H function. See Eq. (2.4), (3.1) and ultimately (3.8)-(3.9) in [this open paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9608346).
So what is the assumption one has to make to express a distribution as a Poisson transform.